# How to extract text data between numbers and semicolon in R?

Tags: r, regex, text, stringr

My desire is to extract texts between numbers begin with either `19` or `20` and semicolons.

```
abc 1993 def ghi; klm
cba 2012 kff kkk; zzz
xxx 1999 ggg yyy; vvv
cgc 2015 tet mmm; bbb
```

Expected output:

```
93 def ghi
12 kff kkk
99 ggg yyy
15 tet mmm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` in base R to capture the characters that succeeds either 19 or 20 and the `;` and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
trimws(sub(".*\\b(19|20)([^;]+);.*", "\\2", str1))
#[1] "93 def ghi" "12 kff kkk" "99 ggg yyy" "15 tet mmm"
```

Or using `trimws` and `whitespace`

```
trimws(str1, whitespace = '.*(19|20)|;.*')
#[1] "93 def ghi" "12 kff kkk" "99 ggg yyy" "15 tet mmm"
```

---

Or with `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
trimws(str_extract(str1, "(?<=\\b(19|20))[^;]+"))
#[1] "93 def ghi" "12 kff kkk" "99 ggg yyy" "15 tet mmm"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("abc 1993 def ghi; klm", "cba 2012 kff kkk; zzz", "xxx 1999 ggg yyy; vvv", 
"cgc 2015 tet mmm; bbb")
```

Comment: The two-digit numbers `19` and `20` should be taken into account. The search for texts begins by referencing to these numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can use `sub` with non-capturing group for 19 and 20 and extract everything after that till semi-colon is encountered.

```
sub('.*(?:19|20)(.*);.*', '\\1', string)
#[1] "93 def ghi" "12 kff kkk" "99 ggg yyy" "15 tet mmm"
```

Using the same regex in `str_match` :

```
stringr::str_match(string, '(?:19|20)(.*);')[, 2]
```